# google map eclipse not working on my emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I search lots of time some answers to my problem but i started a short time coding and i don't succeed in my code. So i ask for your help. Thanks a lot!

So when i run my programm it works (no project errors) but on my emulator it doesn't work, i have this errors in the logcat

My logcat

```
*05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): Process: com.example.carte, PID: 1057
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start         activity ComponentInfo{com.example.carte/com.example.carte.MainActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:76)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at com.example.carte.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-08 04:53:04.448: E/AndroidRuntime(1057):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)*
```

So as i said i try to find solutions: i added

```
 <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in my android manifest, all of errors disappeared but it remained that errors

```
 enter code here`"INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY".
```

my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.carte;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;




import com.example.carte.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


  static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.568, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

            if (map!=null){
              Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                  .title("Hamburg"));
              Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(KIEL)
                  .title("Kiel")
                  .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                  .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                      .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
            }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.carte"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

 <uses-permission android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.carte.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="A----------------------------" />


</application>
```

I add the google library and download all the google extras in the Android SDK manager.

I am french so i ask you to forgive my english... And forgive me the page layout, it's the first time for me, i tried to do my best.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try following this guide:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Also important with Maps V2 is the signing of you project:

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

From what I've quickly read here it seems that you should use your key to sign your project, not in the manifest. Following should be in your manifest instead of the API key:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: I succeed, you were right i added what you say and i follow stricly the links!! thanks!!!

Comment: No problem :). Could you but this as answer though, so the question gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to test your application you should try with some other emulator options like

https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/launchpad/download/
And
http://www.bluestacks.com/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for using the Google Maps you have to test the application on a real device as the emulator is not supported.

if you more details about this please read [Google Maps Android API v2 - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)